Getting actual dimensions of label tcl/tk widget
I try to display some data stored in array with a table-like view.
To do this, I loop through the array and retrieve relevant data into labels which are then used as "table cells".
Each "table row" is run as frame.
Now I need to make the "cells" of certain "column" have same width.
The idea is to retrieve the width of the widest "cell" in the column and apply it to all the other "cells" there.
The amount of data to display is up to couple of thousands rows so I am not concerned about performance issues (although will be happy to see better solutions if possible).
The problem is how to get the actual width of each label?
Using cget option returns "0".
Artificial predicting the max width is not an option :(
Below is the simplified code:
set cnt 0;
set maxWidth 0;
    
foreach {rName rData} [array get SourceArray] { 
        frame .row_${cnt};
        label .row_${cnt}.rName -text $rName;
        label .row_${cnt}.rData -text $rData;

        grid .row_${cnt}.rName  -row $cnt -column 0;
        grid .row_${cnt}.rData  -row $cnt -column 1;

        pack .row_${cnt} -in .ParentFrame -fill x; 

        if {[.row_${cnt}.rName cget -width] > $maxWidth} {set maxWidth [.row_${cnt}.rName cget -width]}
    
        incr cnt 1;
}

# Run "for" loop to further apply the $maxWidth value to all the labels in the "column"


You don't need those evals.

Using evals resolved compilation failures when parsing the variables with the label attributes ($labelDesign). Same was true for the frame but while simplifying my code I've removed the variable and forgot to remove the eval too.

The actual dimensions of a widget are available through winfo width and winfo height, but those are set to dummy values immediately after widget creation, and only become correct after the widget has drawn itself. (Technically, it's after the final <Configure> event is delivered before the first <Map> event.) Before then, you can only usefully use winfo reqwidth/winfo reqheight to get the requested width and height; that's all you really know until the window manager and nested geometry managers finish their negotiations. A widget may get either more or less space than it asked for, and the two dimensions are mostly independent (though some layouts might make that less so, of course).

Indeed winfo gave me the solution. Thank you.
I just had to use update a line before so that the widgets got their real dimensions.
Next challenge was to understand that the received values are actually characters width and then match them to pixels. Tough day :)

I don't usually recommend using update; you can get subtle reentrant bugs that way. Watching for the <Configure> event works better.
